# convert server timestamp to local timestamp

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

Am working in HTML5 + Phonegap - Android Application.
Currently am facing a problem in **convert server timestamp to local timestamp**

From my server i get
**Datetime : 2014-02-07 00:01:15** and **Timestamp : America/New_York**

I want to convert the given time to my device Timestamp.

I got an another Question same like my requirement [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) and I tried this but its failed!
I got this error in Eclipse
[image]

I think its a small issue but didnt get a solution for this !!
Please help me..

or anyone can suggest any other method for the same?? :(

Comment: Are you using the [Globalization API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization/blob/dev/doc/index.md)? You could use that to get the device's timezone and just convert using the Date object.

Comment: Even though you accepted an answer already, i would suggest that a nice way to work this stuff out is by using milliseconds since the Unix epoch: Java: System.currentTimeMillis() Javascript: new Date().getTime(). You can then use GregorianCalendar in Java or new Date(milliseconds) in Javascript to interpret the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Javascript library [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) may help you but you need to use it in combination with moment.js.